# How to use SimpleHttpOperator in Airflow

Tags: airflow

I get error : `http_conn_id http_default isnt defined`  when I run following code:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 2, 27),
    'email': ['ss@asd.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=5),
}
dag = DAG(
    'dag1',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
)
t2 = SimpleHttpOperator(
    task_id='get_labrador',
    method='GET',
    http_conn_id='http_default',
    endpoint='api/breed/labrador/images',
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

What should be my http_conn_id value.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http_conn_id` should contain the name of the Airflow [Connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html) that contains the detail of the url you want to connect to. For example the Hostname to send to Slack Webhook would be `https://hooks.slack.com/`

[image]

Comment: So if I want to do get request to `https://example.com/name/1`  then I would create a `conn_var = https://example.com` and simpleHttpOperator `endpoint = /name/1`

Comment: You need to create a connection from Airflow UI/CLI or using an Environment variable: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#creating-a-connection-with-the-ui and then pass the name of the connection to `http_conn_id`. If you want to do get request to `https://example.com/name/1`, enter Host name as `https://example.com` and in your task `endpoint = /name/1`

Comment: what if it's static value?